Create numeric vector based on the values of a factor with many levels
I am trying to generate a numeric variable dependent on the values of a factor in my dataframe. I have the same number of values as levels of the factor (32). However, attempts to use recode or recode_factor or with str_replace keep failing. I understand that I could use the form a == Apple, b == Banana, but I have 32 factor levels and I need to repeat this operation many times. Is there not a way to do this based on the position in the "pattern" and "replacement" vectors?
In base R, I could do something like this;
df <- data.frame(myString = as.factor(sample(LETTERS, 500, replace = TRUE)))
myValues <- sample(1:1000, 26)
levels(df$myString) <- myValues

Is there not a better way of doing this using dplyr?

What's wrong with your current solution?

Your code, as written, doesn't work very well as you are setting the levels of a data frame, not of the factor column. I assume what you mean is this:
## corrected base R version
## data set up
myData <- data.frame(myString = as.factor(sample(LETTERS, 500, replace = TRUE)))
myValues <- sample(1:1000, 26)

## solution
levels(myData$myString) <- myValues

The way you've done that in base R is great. I would probably do it that way. Another base R method would be to call factor() again and put the desired levels in the labels argument, which relabels them:
## alternate base R solution
myData$myString = factor(myData$myString, labels = myValues)

I don't believe there is a function in forcats that does this. (forcats is the tidyverse package with utility functions for factors).
If you want to use dplyr, the simplest would be to use the factor() again and wrap it in mutate() as it re-assigns the whole vector:
## dplyr version
myData = myData |> 
  mutate(myString = factor(myString, labels = myValues))

If you want to use the direct level assignment (which is probably more efficient, slightly), you could do it this way, though it is unfortunately verbose:
myData |> 
  mutate(across(myString, \(f) {levels(f) = myValues; f}))


Thank you for the answers and apologies for the error in the original code

This could also be a join.
Suppose we have a factor vector of letters, and a lookup table with the letters and what they should become:
library(dplyr)
myString <- data.frame(letters = as.factor(sample(LETTERS, 500, replace = TRUE)))
conversion_table <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS, new_val = sample(1:1000, 26))

myString |>
  left_join(conversion_table)


Probably you can try the code below to recode the factor
myString <- factor(myValues[as.integer(myString)])


You can use functions from dplyr and forcats to recode all your factor columns:
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(myString = as.factor(sample(LETTERS, 500, replace = TRUE)))
myValues <- sample(1:1000, 26)

nm <- setNames(levels(df$myString), as.character(myValues))

df |>
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), \(col) fct_recode(col, !!!nm))) 

# OR 

nm <- setNames(as.character(myValues), levels(df$myString))

df |>
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), \(col) fct_relabel(col, \(x) nm[x])))

Output
#>     myString
#> 1        902
#> 2        882
#> 3        159
#> 4        396
#> 5        451
#> ...

